# how do you create a 2d array that outputs data in a 4 by 4 matrix without using functions?

Tags: python-3.x

we at school have been given a task to create a program that uses arrays. I wanted to complete the task using a 2d array without using functions just to challenge myself.Turns out it was quite the tackle, I've been struggling with that for quite a while now,can anyone help?

well first I tried using the standard way of creating a 2d array,that is: arr=[[0]*4 for i in range(0,4).

and it works well but the problem is that it outputs the rows on the same line. (:()

Comment: Output format is not determined by the data structure, but how you ... output it. You seem to think it is determined by the way you create it. That is not true.

Comment: Please elaborate further.